# Arrow style user defined type guard?

Tags: typescript, types, arrow-functions

The [typescript handbook on user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) defines an example type guard as

```
function isFish(pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish {
    return (<Fish>pet).swim !== undefined;
}
```

Is there a corresponding syntax for arrow functions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

TypeScript supports arrow-function type guards (which may have not been the case in 2017). The following now works as expected. I've used this style frequently in production code:

```
const isFish = (pet: Fish | Bird): pet is Fish => 
  (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use type assertion instead of type declaration:

```
const isFish = (pet => !!pet.swim) as (pet) => pet is Fish
```

However, given the fact that it is more verbose, I would prefer to write type guards as normal functions, unless you really need the `this` binding, but that is probably a code smell.

Answer (score 4):

as an alternative, this also works

```
const isFish = (pet: any): pet is Fish => !!pet.swim;
```

or if you prefer to be more explicit

```
const isFish = (pet: any): pet is Fish => typeof pet.swim === 'function';
```

while the test can be made against properties as well

```
const isFish = (pet: any): pet is Fish => pet.hasOwnProperty('genus');
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just as you would have returned `boolean`, you simply return `pet is Fish`:

```
const isFish: (pet: Fish | Bird) => pet is Fish = pet => (pet as Fish).swim !== undefined
```

Arrow functions are declared as a single type (`(pet: Fish | Bird) => pet is Fish`) rather than the parameters and the return type separately.

Comment: How do I combine the declaration and implementation for arrow functions then? (to make it comparable to the syntax example in the handbook?)

Comment: This gives a compiler error. C.f. this [playground snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Bird%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fly()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20layEggs()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Fish%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20swim()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20layEggs()%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20isFish%3A%20(pet%3A%20Fish%20%7C%20Bird)%20%3D%3E%20pet%20is%20Fish%20%3D%20pet%20%3D%3E%20(pet%20as%20Fish).swim%20!%3D%3D%20undefined%0D%0A)

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
const importList = children.filter(
  (node): node is MeshFullType<Mesh.Import> =>
    code.isMeshFullType(node, Mesh.Import),
)
```